# How can i send spanish message as a single message by using twilio

Tags: java, spring, twilio

I can send SMS message (multiple lines in english) as a single message by using twilio but When I send SMS message(same message) with Spanish translations, the message will get chopped into three messages on the recipients phone. How can i send it as single message.

This is my code

```
public String sendSmsToUser(String to, String body) throws TwilioRestException
    {       
        try
        {
            TwilioRestClient client=new TwilioRestClient(“**************”, “***************”);

            // Build a filter for the MessageList
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", body));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "+"+to));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", twilioConfigBean.getFromNumber()));
            MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory();

            Message message = messageFactory.create(params);

            Message messageStatus=client.getAccount().getMessage(message.getSid());
            return messageStatus.getSid()+"-"+messageStatus.getStatus();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error-"+e;
        }       
    }
```

This is my message body

Please log in to the XYZ app with the following information:Your phone number is 1234567890
Your temporary password is 1234
Do not reply to this message.

Same message in spanish is

Por favor ingresa a la app XYZ con la siguiente información:Tu número de celular es 1234567890
Tu contraseña provisional es 1234
Favor no responder a este mensaje.

Please help me guys

Comment: The GSM standard allows for Max 160 ASCII characters per SMS message, and Max 140 ISO-8859-1 characters. Your Spanish message is longer than this limit, therefore it gets split. It appears that Twilio is sending it as Unicode, which means three messages of up to 67 characters.

Comment: Thank you, but can we do anything to make it as a single message?

Comment: That depends on your phone. Twilio seems to follow the GSM standard, but there are some phones that are not good at putting the messages back together, and also if your phone is not on a GSM network, it may not be able to stitch the messages back together properly. First, try sending to another phone preferably one on a GSM network.